# internet on Wifi doesnt open any site until i connect via a proxy server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, internet-connection, windows-8.1-preview

When i am connecting to a wifi network (tried with different N/Ws) through my laptop, I cant open any website.

At the same time when I use ultrasurf proxy I am able to open the pages, My router is providing the DNS server settings and I can connect without any problems on other devices Like  my iphone.

when I use LAN I am able to open the sites. MY DNS settings are set to "detect automatically"

ipconfig details

```
    Windows IP Configuration


    Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.6
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1

    Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:44e:17dc:53eb:f5f9
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::44e:17dc:53eb:f5f9%8
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{BE60D962-F4C2-47F4-B6E6-6777587862D3}:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Connection details

```
    Description: Qualcomm Atheros AR5007EG Wireless Network Adapter
    Physical Address: ‎00-26-B6-53-18-00
    DHCP Enabled: Yes
    IPv4 Address: 172.20.10.6
    IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
    Lease Obtained: Monday, November 4, 2013 9:17:01 PM
    Lease Expires: Tuesday, November 5, 2013 10:01:40 PM
    IPv4 Default Gateway: 172.20.10.1
    IPv4 DHCP Server: 172.20.10.1
    IPv4 DNS Server: 172.20.10.1
    IPv4 WINS Server:
    NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your DNS server to OpenDNS or Google's DNS?

Comment: yes but no success

Comment: What operating system are you using?  If you really are using the Windows 8.1 Preview you need to migrate to the final version.

Comment: its 8.1 preview, I know I should upgrade to final , but that shouldn't be the reason for this!

Comment: There were hundreds of changes between Preview and RTM that could have made the difference.  Changing your DNS in both locations ( network adapater ) and within the router's configuration should have worked.  Since it didn't work it indicates a OS level problem.

Comment: @Ramhound This problem a few wont happen at all. Just like today I have no problem

Comment: todays Settings  `Connection-specific DNS Suffix: 
Description: Qualcomm Atheros AR5007EG Wireless Network Adapter
Physical Address: ‎00-26-B6-53-18-00
DHCP Enabled: Yes
IPv4 Address: 172.20.10.6
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
Lease Obtained: Tuesday, November 5, 2013 11:08:52 AM
Lease Expires: Wednesday, November 6, 2013 3:12:49 PM
IPv4 Default Gateway: 172.20.10.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 172.20.10.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 172.20.10.1
IPv4 WINS Server: 
NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes`

Comment: Same as before ; the one i posted in the question

Comment: Update your question to reflect this doesn't always happen. You didn't mention that so I figured it was always a problem.  If your unwilling to try solutions I cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure your proxy, are you using a numeric IP address or an address you have defined in your hosts table?

If that's true, the browser could find the proxy without DNS. Then any name resolution which is done via the proxy finds DNS just fine because the *proxy machine* has DNS defined. If you try to connect direct you can't look up a website name and so can't find its numeric IP address. This makes some kind of sense if you access your other local machines with host-defined names or numeric IPs.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=773819)